# 'forget' a collection's item by key within each

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I was wondering if you could `remove` or `forget` an item by key when using `each()` method in Laravel.

I have tried this:

```
$Items = Items::all();
$Items->each(function($Item, $Key){
    if($Item->removable){
        $this->forget($Key);
    }
});
```

And I have also tried this:

```
$Items = Items:all();
$Items->each(function($Item, $Key) use (&$Items){
    if($Item->removable){
        $Items->forget($Key);
    }
});
```

And it seems to just be removing all items instead of the ones that would have my `true` conditional values (in this e.g. `$Item->removable`).

Can anyone shine some light on this?

Comment: I think you need to do `$Items->forget($Item->id)`

Comment: @JagjeetSingh According to the Laravel documentation `forget` uses the collections object/array key to delete/remove items– or have I read this wrong? https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L700

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collections are usually immutable, which means that you can't actually change the underlying data in an object. Operations on a collection often return a new collection containing new items based on the original collection.

You can achieve what you're after using [`filter`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-filter). By passing in a closure, which returns `true` for items that you want to *keep* and `false` for items you want to forget.

```
$Items = $Items->filter(function ($Item, $Key) {
    return ! $Item->removable;
});
```

Or you can use [`reject`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-reject) which does the same as `filter` but in reverse, returning `true` forgets the item from the collection and returning `false` keeps the item in the collection.

```
$Items = $Items->reject(function ($Item, $Key) {
    return $Item->removable;
});
```

These two methods will create a new collection, (in the above examples overwriting `$Items`), containing only values that are *not* considered to be removable.

You could just use the [`forget`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-forget) (The `forget` method is an exception to the immutable rule in that it *does* modify the underlying data) method from outside the collection to remove an item by its key but I don't think that's what you're after.

```
$Items->forget('your_key');
```